# What is the Maximum Common Evility Slots and how can I reach it?

Tags: disgaea-5

Currently, the sardine in Chara World states that I can't up my evility slot count. My character has 10 common evility slots, plus 3 common evility "2" slots. Current level is at 395.

What other way can I increase evility slots other than, from what I have read, defeating Miss Heart (Evil?) in Chara World.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://www.justpushstart.com/2015/10/disgaea-5-unlock-every-evility-slot/), you can have a maximum of **20** common evility slots. Here is how you get them:

> - Level up (1 – 12)
> - Complete Chara World Reward (13 – 17)
> - Defeat Miss Evil the secret Super Overlord difficulty Chara World boss (18 – 20)

Note that the first twelve will be fully unlocked once your character hits level 9999 for the first time.